# Is it possible to test my App Action integrated Slice from Google Assistant?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, android-slices, app-actions

I have implemented the App Actions in a demo app. It's working fine and I'm able to launch a specific screen using Google Assistant with queries like

> Order pizza from Avocado

So I started to integrate Slice. When testing the Slice using [SliceViewer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SliceViewer), it works fine.

But when I try to invoke Slice from Google Assistant, it doesn't work.

Here is the snippet in the actions.xml

```xml
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_ORDER">
    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
        urlTemplate="content://my.food.service/status" />

    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
        urlTemplate="my://food/orders" />
</action>
```

The queries I used in Google Assistant are from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/)

> - Ask Avocado to check my order
> - Check my order on Avocado

But neither works.

Also, after I added the above snippet to the actions.xml, I am not able to use the "App Actions Test Tool" plugin anymore. It says

> Preview Creation Error Status Code: 400 Message: Precondition check failed. - Multiple URL templates for action 'actions.intent.GET_ORDER' have zero required parameters.

I'm using plugin version v1.1.0

**So my question is:**
Is testing Slice through Google Assistant available? If not, when will it be available to develop and test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is testing Slice through Google Assistant
>   available? If not, when will it be available to develop and test?

Yes, developing/testing Slice fulfillment via Google Assistant using the Studio Test Tool should already work.

Can you try removing the `DEEPLINK` fulfillment block and see if that works? So your `actions.xml` would look like:

```
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_ORDER">
    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
        urlTemplate="content://my.food.service/status" />    
</action>
```

Explanation: a particular `<action>` must have one, and only one `<fulfillment>` block that has zero `<parameter>` blocks that have `required=true`. Why? Because that becomes the "fallback" fulfillment mechanism as noted in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/reference/actionsxml#fulfillment):

> You must provide one `<fulfillment>` without any required parameters as
>   a fallback fulfillment.

As `actions.intent.GET_ORDER` doesn't accept any parameters, that means you can only ever have a single `<fulfillment>` block which can either be fulfilled via Slice or Deep Link, but not both.

Comment: That's it! After removing the `DEEPLINK` fulfillment block, the Test Tool is back to work, and I'm able to show Slice from Google Assistant using those queries. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have issues test slices with google assistant. My assistant is stuck on loading the reply while deeplink is working fine.